# How do I escape a colon in Python format() when using kwargs?

Tags: python, string-formatting

I have a dictionary with a colon in a key that I wish to print. Unfortunately the colon character is used for formatting, so I need to somehow escape it.

For example:

```
>>> d = {'hello': 'world', 'with:colon': 'moo'}

>>> '{hello}'.format(**d)
'world'

>>> '{with:colon}'.format(**d)
KeyError: 'with'

>>> '{with\:colon}'.format(**d)
KeyError: 'with\\'

>>> '{with::colon}'.format(**d)
KeyError: 'with'
```

Comment: Same issue with `{'with!exclaim':something}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a workaround:

```
>>> d = {'hello': 'world', 'with:colon': 'moo'}
>>> '{hello} {}'.format(d['with:colon'],**d)
'world moo'
>>> '{hello} {0}'.format(d['with:colon'],**d)
'world moo'
```

Answer (score 10):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), what you are asking is simply not possible. Specifically,

> Because arg_name is not quote-delimited, it is not possible to specify arbitrary dictionary keys (e.g., the strings `'10'` or `':-]'`) within a format string.

Comment: Can not unsee the robotic smiley face `:-]`

Answer (score 2):

You can't - the keys must be syntactically equivalent to Python identifiers.  See [Format String Syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) in the documentation:

```
replacement_field ::=  "{" [field_name] ["!" conversion] [":" format_spec] "}"
field_name        ::=  arg_name ("." attribute_name | "[" element_index "]")*
arg_name          ::=  [identifier | integer]
attribute_name    ::=  identifier
```

Answer (score 2):

As of python 3.6 you can solve this with the new f-string formating:

```
>>> d = {'hello': 'world', 'with:colon': 'moo'}
>>> print(f"with:colon is equal to {d['with:colon']}")
with:colon is equal to moo
```

Answer (score 1):

As [@murgatroid99](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19913567/722121) points out in his answer, this isn't possible.

A work-around would be to replace the keys with keys that are valid:

```
d_sanitised = {key.replace(":", "-"): value for key, value in d.items()}
```

Naturally, you might want to be careful if there is the possibility of conflicts with other keys.

```
>>> d = {'hello': 'world', 'with:colon': 'moo'}
>>> d_sanitised = {key.replace(":", "-"): value for key, value in d.items()}
>>> '{with-colon}'.format(**d_sanitised)
'moo'
```

Obviously, this assumes you can modify your format strings to suit. Ideally, just modify both ends to avoid colons all together.

Answer (score 1):

It's a pity that the built-in formatter doesn't allow that. An obvious syntax extension would be to allow keys to be quoted, if necessary. Your format string would be then like this:

```
format('{"with:colon"} and {hello}'
```

Fortunately, it appears to be easy to extend the Formatter to provide this syntax, here's a POC implementation:

```
class QuotableFormatter(string.Formatter):
    def __init__(self):
        self.super = super(QuotableFormatter, self)
        self.super.__init__()
        self.quotes = {}

    def parse(self, format_string):
        fs = ''
        for p in re.findall(r'(?:".+?")|(?:[^"]+)', format_string):
            if p[0] == '"':
                key = '_q_' + str(len(self.quotes))
                self.quotes[key] = p[1:-1]
                fs += key
            else:
                fs += p
        return self.super.parse(fs)

    def get_field(self, field_name, args, kwargs):
        if field_name.startswith('_q_'):
            field_name = self.quotes[field_name]
        return self.super.get_field(field_name, args, kwargs)
```

Usage:

```
d = {'hello': 'world', 'with:colon': 'moo', "weird!r:~^20": 'hi'}
print QuotableFormatter().format('{"with:colon":*>20} and {hello} and {"weird!r:~^20"}', **d)
# *****************moo and world and hi
```

Comment: +1, nice solution - it's unfortunate it makes the syntax awkward, but if this is a common problem in the OP's code, this is by far the best solution.

Comment: @Lattyware: yeah, perhaps escaping would be nicer, like `{with\:colon}`.